# Problema ao instanciar classes no Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quando executo o meu programa `test.py`: o *debug* me devolve

> object() takes no parameters '' na linha 4

```
from tatu2 import Cliente
from tatu2 import Conta

joao = Cliente('João da Silva', '777-1234')
maria = Cliente('Maria da Silva', '555-4321')
conta1 = Conta([joao], 1, 1000)
conta2 = Conta([maria, joao], 2, 500)
conta1.saque(50)
conta2.deposito(300)
conta1.saque(190)
conta2.deposito(95.15)
conta2.saque(250)
conta1.extrato()
conta2.extrato()
```

[image: Código da minha Classe]

Comment: Coloque o código do arquivo `tatu2.py` e a **mensagem completa do erro** na pergunta também. Aproveite e faça o [tour] para aprender o básico do funcionamento do site e leia o guia de [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua Classes estão com os **init** escritos de forma errada. Você está escrevendo:

```
class Cliente:
    def __int__ (self, nome, telefone):
```

E o correto seria:

```
class Cliente:
    def __init__(self, nome, telefone):
```