# Erro ao instanciar objetos em python OO

Tags: python-3.x

Galera, vou reunir aqui nesta mensagem duas dúvidas de python OO. Uso anaconda (python 3.6.1).

Estou tentando fazer um projetinho para estudar a orientação a objeto no python 3.6.1. Inicialmente, o problema é na hora de passar os parâmetros para o construtor.

```
# coding: UTF-8
from automovel import Veiculo

class Veiculo(object):

    #como atribuo valores de instância para essas variáveis como no java, por exemplo?

    placa=None
    cor=None
    cidade=None

    #construtor

    def __init__(self, placa, cidade, cor):
        self.placa=placa
        self.cor=cor
        self.cidade=cidade

    # a linha abaixo não dá erro, mas não usa o construtor
    carro=Veiculo

    # a linha abaixo dá erro e nem usa o construtor
    carro2 = Veiculo("JFW3128", "Salvador", "preto")
```

O erro:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Unresolved import: Veiculo  automovel.py    /automoveis line 7  PyDev Problem

Já sem a linha do import, dá o erro:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Undefined variable: Veiculo automovel.py    /automoveis line 13 PyDev Problem

Obs, o nome do arquivo é automovel.py. Uso a IDE eclipse com o pydev instalado.

Sei que há tantas teorias na OO, como no link:

[Atribuição e OO em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/223398/atribui%c3%a7%c3%a3o-e-oo-em-python)

Prefiro me ater a parte concreta mesmo.

Neste link, parece-me que o python OO funciona tranquilamente (python v2):

[Imprimir uma lista de objetos como string em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143267/imprimir-uma-lista-de-objetos-como-string-em-python)

Já a mesma dúvida a seguir não houve um retorno de satisfação do usuário:

[Problema ao instanciar classes no Python 3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/250065/problema-ao-instanciar-classes-no-python-3)

Comment: O nome do arquivo é `Veiculo`, que importa o módulo `Veiculo` (ele mesmo) e define uma classe `Veiculo`? Esse é o erro. O que exatamente é esse `import`?

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss já tentei com o nome diferente para o arquivo, mas não percebi muita mudança. O import Veiculo é a classe e, consequentemente, o arquivo. Acredito que mesmo assim não deveria dar erro porque o python não leva em conta o nome do arquivo. Há framework, por exemplo, que têm várias classes num mesmo arquivo.

Comment: O nome do arquivo será o nome do módulo, então é levado em conta, sim. A questão é: por quê está importando o módulo dentro dele mesmo, sendo que ele mesmo define a classe? O conflito de nomes está entre o nome do módulo e o nome da classe, não pode ser o mesmo.

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss refiz o projeto, revi os erros e editei a pergunta.

Comment: Mas ainda você está importando o próprio módulo nele mesmo? Isso não faz sentido. Por quê o `import automovel` dentro do próprio arquivo `automovel`?

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss o por quê da importação da classe dentro do próprio arquivo é citado na pergunta, apontando para o segundo erro mostrado.

Comment: vc está intanciando  a mesma classe dentro dela mesmo  quando  informa que carro2 = Veiculo ? talvez o erro está ai, pois você pode acabar gerando um loop eterno, tente chamar fora dessa classe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está pensando muito "javamente". Esse código ai pode ser pythonizado.

Em python, o que define o escopo é a indentação.

Por exemplo:

```
def function(a):
    if a is None:
        b = 100
        return b

    if a > 300:
        c = 90
        return a + c

    #erro, b e c não estão definidas nesse escopo.
    # b só pode ser referenciada dentro do primeiro if.
    # c só pode ser referenciada dentro do segundo if.
    return c*b*90
```

No seu caso, a sua classe `Veiculo` tem dentro do seu escopo tudo que está indentado com quatro espaços ou um tab, que são:

- As variáveis que você definiu: `placa`, `cor` e `cidade`.
- O construtor: `def __init__(self, placa, cidade, cor)`.
- E as chamadas: `carro=Veiculo` e `carro2 = Veiculo("JFW3128", "Salvador", "preto")`

Primeiro ponto, você não precisa declarar as variáveis antes de atribuir algum valor à elas. Ou seja, é inútil fazer isso:

```
placa=None
cor=None
cidade=None
```

Você não precisa extender `Veiculo` à `Object`. É a mesma coisa que fazer: `class Veiculo:`

Sempre que você der um `self.attr` você vai estar criando um atributo da classe, caso ele não exista ainda. Segundo a [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), todos os atributos da classe devem ser criados no construtor. Ou seja, a primeira declaração deles devem ser no `__init__`. Nesse ponto, seu código está certo.

Você não precisa importar um módulo se você já tem acesso à ele. Então, também é inútil fazer o import que você fez.

Código pythonizado:

```
class Veiculo:

    def __init__(self, placa, cidade, cor):
        self.placa = placa
        self.cor = cor
        self.cidade = cidade

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "({0};{1};{2})".format(self.placa, self.cor, self.cidade)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    carro = Veiculo
    carro2 = Veiculo("JFW3128", "Salvador", "preto")
    print(carro)
    print(carro2)
```

Porque `if __name__ == "__main__":`?

O interpretador do python executa todo o código conforme lê ele.
Se, por algum motivo, em outro arquivo você der um `from automovel import Veiculo` e não tiver essa verificação da variável `__name__` ele vai executar essa parte do código sem você ter chamado `python automovel.py`.
Ou seja, ele só vai executar essa parte do código de a execução do script for feita por `python automovel.py`.

Answer (score 3):

Existem dois problemas aí. Vamos por partes, primeiro retire essa linha do import e retire a indentação da variável carro e carro2:

```
class Veiculo(object):

    placa=None
    cor=None
    cidade=None

    #construtor

    def __init__(self, placa, cidade, cor):
        self.placa=placa
        self.cor=cor
        self.cidade=cidade

# Se as linhas abaixo estiverem indentadas como estavam inicialmente,
# ou seja, no mesmo nível de Veiculo,
# significa que as variáveis fazem parte da classe Veiculo, e você
# não vai conseguir declarar uma var Veiculo dentro dele mesmo

carro = Veiculo
carro2 = Veiculo("JFW3128", "Salvador", "preto")
```

Agora você pode recortar as variáveis **carro** e **carro2** e salvar o arquivo só com a classe **Veiculo**, e então sim importar ele em outro arquivo, e colar as linhas de carro e carro2 neste novo arquivo